# Can I reuse the window/orphan mechanism of section titles to bind something else (like theorems with their proofs)?

Tags: page-breaking, thmtools, widows-orphans

LaTeX layout mechanism can somehow try to avoid window/orphan paragraphs and section titles, i.e. it's very rare (or impossible?) for a section title to appear at the end of a page with the first paragraph of the section on the next page.

Can I reuse this mechanism to bind other elements? In particular, I usually theorems with the environments provided by the `thmtools` package and the corresponding proofs are usually enclosed in a `proof` environment. What happens is that often the theorem statement appears at the end of the page and its proof starts on the next one.

While this is not as far as bad as it would be if it happened with section titles, it's still undesirable.

Is it a way to bind together two elements of the page in order to avoid them being separated in different pages?

Comment: this is impractical; i don't know that it's impossible, but certainly not easy.  it often happens in published mathematics that non-theorem/proof text intervenes between a theorem and its proof.  this would have to be accounted for in the kind of association you request, and might well prove more of a hindrance to an author than letting things happen as they do now.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That seems like a good reason not to, say, ask for the `thmtools` package to do this. But I read the question not as a feature request but more as a how-can-I-adapt-this-in-my-document question. If the OP always follows the theorem statement by the proof, then the requested behaviour might well be reasonable in this case. Of course, there might be technical difficulties implementing it, but that would be a different kind of problem, surely?

Comment: @cfr -- given the way that theorem environments are defined, the ending goes into vertical mode with a defined vertical space.  that would have to be trapped ahead of the space, and a "no break" condition inserted; won't work after the fact.  maybe a "need space" approach could be taken, but that would require manual attention for every instance.  doesn't bode well for automatic recognition and application.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That's a different problem, though i.e. cannot reasonably be implemented for technical reasons. At least, I think so. That's all I meant.

Comment: @gigabytes make what you may wish you could bring problems with vertical space. In any case, it could do more with the wording in general or add some information so that the theorem does not remain at the bottom of each page.

Comment: As @cfr said, this is a question about how to do it in my specific case, I don't say it's a good idea to do it for any theorem anywhere. Anyway I understand the difficulties in make it work after the fact. Maybe it could be easier to imagine a theorem environment that could _enclose_ its proof counterpart? like `\begin{theorem}blahblah\begin{proof}blahblah\end{proof}\end{theorem}`. In this case maybe it could be feasible?